# R: Why isn't this matrix 3d linear interpolation working correctly?

Tags: r, matrix, interpolation, linear-interpolation

I have a matrix of values and zeros, where zero= `NA`. The values are interspersed around the matrix, and what I want to do is interpolate the values of all the `NA` values. This is the data:

[image]

I'm trying to guess all of these values by taking all the known values in my matrix, and multiplying the value by the distance (such that the further away a point is, the less influence it has). This is what the interpolated result looks like:
[image]

As you can see, this method is not very effective, it *does* affect the `NA`s nearest to the known values, but then they quickly converge onto an average value. I think this is due to the fact that it's taking the ENTIRE RANGE, which has many ups and downs... rather than just the points nearest to it.

Obviously, matrix operations aren't my specialty... what do I need to change to correctly do the linear-interpolation?

Here's the code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

Cont <- structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1816, 2320, 1406, 2028, 1760, 1932, 1630, 
                    1835, 1873, 1474, 1671, 2073, 1347, 2131, 2038, 1969, 2036, 1602, 
                    1986, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2311, 1947, 2094, 1947, 2441, 1775, 1461, 1260, 
                    1494, 2022, 1863, 1587, 2082, 1567, 1770, 2065, 1404, 1809, 1972, 
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                    0, 0, 0, 2314, 1595, 2065, 1870, 2178, 1410, 1994, 1979, 2111, 
                    1531, 1917, 1559, 2109, 1921, 1606, 1469, 1601, 1771, 1771), .Dim = c(19L, 
                                                                                       30L))

  ## First get real control values
  idx <- which(Cont > 0, arr.ind=TRUE)
  V <- Cont[idx]
  ControlValues <- data.frame(idx,V)

  ## Make data.frame of values to fill
  toFill <- which(Cont == 0, arr.ind=TRUE) %>% as.data.frame
  toFill$V <- 0

  ## And now figure out the weighted value of each point
  for (i in 1:nrow(toFill)){
    toFill[i,] -> CurrentPoint

    Xs <- (1/abs(CurrentPoint[,1] - ControlValues[,1])) 
    Xs[is.infinite(Xs)] <- 0
    Xs <- Xs/sum(Xs)/100

    Ys <- (1/abs(CurrentPoint[,2] - ControlValues[,2])) 
    Ys[is.infinite(Ys)] <- 0
    Ys <- Ys/sum(Ys)/100

    ControlValues1 <- data.frame(Xs,Ys)
    toFill[i,3] <- sum(rowMeans(ControlValues1) * ControlValues$V)*100
  }

  ## add back in the controls and reorder
  bind_rows(ControlValues,toFill) -> Both
  Both %>% arrange(row,col) -> Both

  ## and plot the new surface
  NewCont <- matrix(Both$V,max(Both$row),max(Both$col),byrow = T)
  plot_ly(z=NewCont, type="surface",showscale=FALSE)
```

Comment: You won't be able to *interpolate* the values for `x < 10` because your data has no support there. If you are only interested in the interpolated values for the range `10 <= x <= 30`, you can use bi-linear interpolation.

Comment: A fair point. I'd like to interpolate AND extrapolate. Isn't what I did bi-linear interpolation?

Comment: I don't think your code does bi-linear interpolation. Also, just fair warning that extrapolation in your case will have little value since your data is so sparse.

Comment: I'd really appreciate to see a working example, as I mentioned, matrix operations aren't my strong point. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to interpolate and extrapolate data in R is to use the `akima` package. The following performs bi-linear interpolation followed by extrapolation using as input the known data points in the data frame `ControlValues` to fill the zeroes in `Cont`.

```
library(akima)
library(plotly)

NewCont <- akima::interp(x=ControlValues[,1], y=ControlValues[,2], z=ControlValues[,3],
                         xo=1:nrow(Cont), yo=1:ncol(Cont), linear=TRUE)$z
NewCont[,1:9] <- akima::interp.old(x=ControlValues[,1], y=ControlValues[,2], 
                                   z=ControlValues[,3], xo=1:nrow(Cont), 
                                   yo=1:9, ncp=2, extrap=TRUE)$z

plot_ly(z=NewCont, type="surface",showscale=FALSE)
```

Notes:

1. The first call to `akima::interp` performs the bi-linear interpolation. See the help page `?akima::interp` for usage and details.

   - A key point is that the inputs `x`, `y`, and `z` for the known data points need not be on a `x-y` grid. In this case, these are the columns of `ControlValues`.
   - The output of `akima::interp` is a list whose `z` component is a matrix of interpolated values over the grid whose `x` and `y` coordinates are defined by the inputs `xo` and `yo`, respectively. In this case, these are just the row and column indices of `Cont`
   - As stated in the help page

   > z-values for points outside the convex hull are returned as `NA`.

   In this case, the first nine columns of the output corresponding to `yo=1:9` will be `NA`s.
2. The second call to `akima::interp` (actually `akima::interp.old`) performs the data extrapolation to fill in the `NA`s left by the first call. See [this SO quation/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29364470/extrapolation-beyond-a-grid-of-data) for the details of this usage.

The above approach gives the following result

[image: NewCont]

Another approach to perform bi-linear interpolation is to use the `interp.surface` function in the `fields` package. This approach is mentioned because the implementation is an R-script, which can be listed by typing the function name `interp.surface` at the R command line.

```
library(fields)

loc <- make.surface.grid(list(x=1:nrow(Cont), y=1:ncol(Cont)))
NewCont2 <- matrix(interp.surface(list(x=sort(unique(ControlValues[,1])),
                                       y=sort(unique(ControlValues[,2])),
                                       z=matrix(ControlValues[,3],
                                                nrow=length(unique(ControlValues[,1])),
                                                ncol=length(unique(ControlValues[,2])))),
                                  loc), nrow=nrow(Cont), ncol=ncol(Cont))
NewCont2[,1:9] <- akima::interp.old(x=ControlValues[,1], y=ControlValues[,2], 
                                    z=ControlValues[,3], xo=1:nrow(Cont), 
                                    yo=1:9, ncp=2, extrap=TRUE)$z
```

Here, the requirements are the opposite to those for `akima::interp`. Specifically, the known data points must lie on a `x-y` grid. However, the coordinates to interpolate need not be on a grid and is instead a matrix containing corresponding column vectors of `x` and `y` coordinates where each tuple `(x[i],y[i])` is a `x-y` coordinate to interpolate. Since the data points in `ControlValues` are on a grid, these requirements are also satisfied for this case. See the help page `?interp.surface` for usage and details.

Notes:

1. `sort(unique(ControlValues[,1]))` and `sort(unique(ControlValues[,2]))` simply gives the `x` and `y` coordinates for the grid of known data points
2. The `z` component in the list is simply the `z` values for the known data points reshaped as a matrix over the grid of known data points
3. The matrix of coordinates to interpolate is generated by `make.surface.grid` using as `x` and `y` coordinates the row and column indices of `Conf`, respectively
4. A coordinate to interpolate that lies outside the grid of known points will result in a interpolated value of `NA`
5. `interp.surface` returns a vector of `z` values corresponding to the coordinates to interpolate. This is then rehaped to a matrix over the grid of coordinates to interpolate, which has dimensions `nrow(Cont)` by `ncol(Cont)`

Finally, it is easy to verify that the two approaches give the same result

```
print(max(abs(NewCont - NewCont2)))
##[1] 4.547474e-13
```

Comment: Excellent answer. I was even going to ask about how to compare the interpolation methods, but it's great that you even showed that at the end. Wonderful! Incredible that the two methods are so close... I guess the interpolation algorithm is very similar? The other thing I'm noticing, which is a bit annoying is that the peaks and valleys are too extreme... If I'm interested in building a  baseline control surface, maybe I should apply some smoothening first. Is there some correct way to do it? Or is it fair to just multiply all my values by `0.8` or so? Thanks again!

Comment: @AmitKohli sorry for the delay in getting back to you. For your first question, the short answer is that the algorithm in `akima` is more sophisticated because it does not require a grid of known points to interpolate. The algorithm in `fields`, however, is what people would normally refer to as bi-linear interpolation. This requires a grid of known points, which your data happens to satisfy. For the answer to your second question, see my next comment.

Comment: @AmitKohli the correct way all depends on the meaning of your data. If your data is known to be perfectly accurate, then you should interpolate (and can extrapolate). For additional smoothness, you may want to interpolate using a higher order function such as cubic splines. If your data is known to be noisy, then you want to fit some function to these data points that minimizes some error criterion. This is estimation. Here, the function can be linear or higher-order. The difference is that fitting will generally not preserve the values of the data represented by the estimated function.

Comment: this is exactly the kind of help I'm looking for. I can tell you a little bit more about this project... I'm trying to help my dad (a wheat breeder) use a better way of interpreting experimental wheat yields relative to control varieties that are interspersed throughout the field. Would you like to collaborate? I don't know if you're involved in development, but this could be a really useful tool for people who really need it! I would be very interested to hear your perspective looking at the real data. Interested in doing your part? :)  https://github.com/mexindian/lineSelector